# Trying to solve a third-order homogeneous differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is this :

$$\dfrac{d^3y}{dx^3} + \dfrac{d(\ln(f(x)))}{dx}\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\Big[1 + f(x)^2 \Big]\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{d(\ln(f(x)))}{dx}y = 0.$$

The function $f(x)$ is non-zero and positive in its interval of definition. How would I approach this problem? I apologise for not showing any work done as I am all out of ideas.

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution in closed form? Maybe you can apply the Lie series technique. Otherwise, maybe a numerical solution for given $f$ is enough?

Comment: @Wauzl I was looking for an analytical solution.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Without fixing the form of $f(x)$ it is very unlikely that you will have a chance in getting a closed form solution. Even when using symmetry methods of Lie. how did you derive this ODE? If you used a Lagrangian to derive this ODE, you could try to use Noether's Theorem to construct conservation laws for this ODE, and reduce the order of the system. Or you could simply try to use the general method for finding conservation laws for ODEs.

Comment: As @Wauzl mentioned this equation is a linear equation. If you use the first order representation you could use the Peano-Baker series to express the solution. But I think that this will not help you either as the series will most likely have no closed form solution.

Comment: @MrYouMath The Ode actually came out while looking at a transformation of space curves. It is quite similar to what one would get by eliminating tangent and normal terms from Frenet equations. However, a solution in the form of $r(C. y)$ has been suggested...an inner product solution where r is a scalar and C a vector function

Answer (score 2):

You could try to solve it via Lie series:
First, rewrite your ODE as a first order system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a'\\b'\\c'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b\\c\\-c f'/f -
 b(1+f^2) - a f'/f\end{bmatrix}$$
with $a=a(x)=y(x)$, $b=b(x)$, $c=c(x)$ and $f'/f=(f'/f)(x)=\frac d{dx}\ln(f(x))$.

Now we define the differential operator $D$ with
$$ D = b\partial_a + c\partial_b - (c f'/f +
 b(1+f^2) + a f'/f)\partial_c. $$
The operator $D$ basically interprets the vector on the right hand side of our system as a derivative. Now we can write our system in the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}a'\\b'\\c'\end{bmatrix} = D\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}Da\\Db\\Dc\end{bmatrix}$$
and we know the solution to it know immediatly:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \exp\bigl((x-x_0) D\bigr)\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\b_0\\c_0\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\bigl(x_0, (a_0,b_0,c_0)\bigr) = \bigl(x_0, (y(x_0),y'(x_0),y''(x_0))\bigr)$ are the initial data for your original problem.

The only difficulty is now, to calculate
$$\exp(t D) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} D^k, $$
where $D^0g(a,b,c) = g(a,b,c)$ and $D^kg(a,b,c) = D^{k-1}\bigl(Dg(a,b,c)\bigr)$. In this case we would have, e.g. (with $\phi=f'/f$)
\begin{align*}D^2 &= \bigl(b\partial_a + c\partial_b - (c \phi +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\partial_c\bigr)\bigl(b\partial_a + c\partial_b - (c \phi +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\partial_c\bigr) \\
&= \phantom{{}+{}}b^2\partial_{aa} + bc\partial_{ba} - b\phi\partial_c - b(c \phi +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\partial_{cc} \\
&\phantom{{}={}}{}+ c\partial_a + cb\partial_{ba} + c^2\partial_{bb} - c(1+f^2)\partial_c - c(c \phi +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\partial_{bc}\\
&\phantom{{}={}}{} - (c f'/f +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\bigl(b\partial_{ca} + c\partial_{cb} - \phi\partial_c - (c f'/f +
 b(1+f^2) + a \phi)\partial_{cc} \bigr).
\end{align*}
All you have to do is to find a general formula for $D^k$ and you have your analytic solution as a series. Maybe a computer-algebra program can help with that. (Also I'm not sure if my calculation of $D^2$ is correct.)

---

EDIT:
I just thought to myself that, since you will apply $D^k$ to $[a_0,b_0,c_0]^T$, you can drop all partial derivatives or order higher than one.

---

EDIT:
And of course: This method is a little overkill, since your ODE is linear:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a'\\b'\\c'\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\-  f'/f&-(1+f^2)&- f'/f\end{bmatrix}}_{=A=A(x)}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
your solution is given by the formula
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty I_k \begin{bmatrix}a_0\\b_0\\c_0\end{bmatrix},$$
where $I_0$ is the identity matrix and $I_k(x) = \int_{x_0}^x A(\xi) I_{k-1}(\xi)\,d\xi$. This is known as the Peano-Baker series method. Now you only have to find a formula for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty I_k$, meaning you need a formula for $I_k$.

Comment: +1: For the Lie Series approach. Didn't know one could actually use this series for solving the ODE directly. Do you know any source that is explaining this method?

Comment: [This](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X8490057X) paper from Stanley Steinberg (1984), maybe? I'm sure there are other sources, as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this paper. I will have a look at it as soon I have more spare time :).